# Hosting Symfony 3 inside subdirectory on IIS

Tags: symfony, iis

I have a really harsh time trying to get Symfony 3 app work on IIS as website subdirectory.

Structure on IIS :

[image]

Application is called pfc and its poiting to directory pfc/web, (IIS is hiding root, because folder name is same as app)

This is web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <defaultDocument>
        <files>
          <add value="app_dev.php" />
        </files>
      </defaultDocument>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <clear />
          <rule name="StaticFiles" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
          </rule>
          <rule name="Symfony 3" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".?" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
              <action type="Rewrite" url="./app_dev.php" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Entering dev.erp.loc/Test2/pfc ends up with:

[image]

like Symfony thinks of itself as a root application, which is not.

My best shoot was to use **router.request_context.base_url**, but it looks like it worked only in S2.

**Now im stuck on something i can call half-way solution**

By comment *rewrite* section in web.config i was correctly redirected to Identity Server, but after log in i get :

[image]

In order to fix it, i needed to uncomment *rewrite* section, to make routing work again, but it works only for browser, leaving it in this state will cause "no route found" in anther browser.

**It would be nice to fix subdirectory routing in parameters.yml, which I fill anyway in deploy script, but if there is no other way I can edit web.config too.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I needed to take care of similar issue and as side effect I solved this "problem". My URL **without** trailing slash is [correct](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/33074). The issue was that Chrome couldn't create *canonical url form* and made request to endpoint that **Symfony don't need to interpret**